# Check if vector has all possible combinations of characters

Tags: c++

I have found many other questions that have asked how to create all possible combinations of 'A' 'B' 'C' into a vector but 
I am trying to find a simpler way how in which to check if my vector which contains many different and the same combinations of 'A' 'B' 'C' (with repetition Eg. AAA and CAA) contains all possible combinations of those three characters.

I was going to make each different combination of the characters equal a different number and have a switch statement like below which changed each case to true when matched and at the end have an if statement checking if all cases where true.

But I feel as if there is a much easier way to do this...

I'm still new to c++ so any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated

```
vector<string> myVector = {"ABC", "CBA"};
bool case1 = false;
for(int i = 0; i < myVector.size(); i++){
    switch(myVector[i]){
        case 11:
            case1 = true;
            break;
        ...
    }        
}
```

Comment: I think [next_permutation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/next_permutation) is what you're looking for.

Comment: Note: `myVector[i]` is a `string`. You cannot `switch` on a `string` in C++.

Answer (score 0):

- Store all permutations of the string in a `vector`
- Compare that to the input vector

A minimal example would look like this:

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    std::string s = "ABC";

    std::vector<string> perString;
    std::vector<string> inputVector = {"ABC", "ACB", "BAC", "BCA", "CAB", "CBA"}; 
    do {
        perString.push_back(s);
    } while(std::next_permutation(s.begin(), s.end()));
    if(perString == inputVector)
        std::cout<< "YES, the vector has all possible combinations of characters" << '\n';
    else
        std::cout<< "NO, It doesn't" << '\n';       

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Not all of these combinations are permutations though {"AAA","AAB","AAC","ABA","ABB","ABC","ACA","ACB","ACC","BAA","BAB","BAC","BBA","BBB","BBC","BCA","BCB","BCC","CAA","CAB","CAC","CBA","CBB","CBC","CCA","CCB","CCC"}

Comment: I did not know if it was with repetitions

Comment: Any solutions for repetition?

Comment: std function not available for this. But examples available online. Check this link: https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/combinations-with-repetitions/

Comment: After finding all combinations with repetitions, you can compare the vectors

Answer (score 0):

- Filter your vector to have only valid string (so reject `"AZA"` if you want only letters from `'A'`, `'B'`, `'C'`)
- `std::sort`/`std::unique` its content. (so `"AAA", "ABA", "AAA"}` -> `{"AAA", "ABA"}`).
- then check vector size with expected size (`3 ** 3` or `27` in your case (`$alphabetSize ** $stringSize`)).

Answer (score 0):

One way to solve this problem is to sort the vector of combinations to be checked (if it isn't already) and then compare the elements with all the possible (sorted) combinations. The time complexity of this approach, due to the sorting phase, is O(C * log C), where C is the number of elements of the inputted vector.

C can be quite big, given **n** as the number of possible elements and **k** the number of elements selected, all the possible combination with repetitions is **n**<sup>**k**</sup> (in OP's example, it's 3 ^ 3 = 27).

A different approach, that does not require to sort the initial vector, nor to actually generate the sorted combinations, is similar to the search of a value in an hash table.

If all the combinations can be sorted, they can be indexed too. So you can calculate the "index" of a particular combination represented by the string that you are testing and count the number of valid combinations found.

This is a possible implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// Transforms a string representing a combination into the index of that
// combination in the set of all possible combinations
size_t index_of(std::string const &candidate, std::string const &source);

// Check if the the vector 'combs' contains all the possible combinations
// of 'k' elements of string 'base'
bool are_there_all_the_possible_combinations(std::string const &base,
                                             size_t k,
                                             std::vector<std::string> const &combs);

int main()
{
    std::string base {"ABC"};

    std::vector<std::string> combs {
        "AAA", "AAB", "AAC", "ABA", "ABB", "ABC", "ACA", "ACB", "ACC",
        "BAA", "BAB", "BAC", "BBA", "BBB", "BBC", "BCA", "BCB", "BCC",
        "CAA", "CAB", "CAC", "CBA", "CBB", "CBC", "CCA", "CCB", "CCC"
    };

    size_t k = 3;

    std::cout << ( are_there_all_the_possible_combinations(base, k, combs)
                 ? "Yes\n" : "No\n" );              // <-- it should output 'Yes'

    combs.erase( std::remove( combs.begin(), combs.end(), "BCA" ), combs.end() );

    std::cout << ( are_there_all_the_possible_combinations(base, k, combs)
                 ? "Yes\n" : "No\n" );              // <-- it should output 'No'

    combs.push_back("BCA");              // <-- Note that now the vector isn't sorted.

    std::cout << ( are_there_all_the_possible_combinations(base, k, combs)
                 ? "Yes\n" : "No\n" );              // <-- it should output 'Yes'
}

// Calculate base ^ exponent (using size_t, not floating point math)
constexpr size_t ull_pow(size_t base, size_t exponent)
{
    size_t result = 1;
    for (;;)
    {
        if (exponent & 1)
            result *= base;
        exponent >>= 1;
        if (exponent == 0)
            break;
        base *= base;
    }
    return result;
}


// Counts the number of valid combinations and check if it equals the total
bool are_there_all_the_possible_combinations(std::string const &base,
                                             size_t k,
                                             std::vector<std::string> const &combs)
{
    size_t total_combinations = ull_pow(base.size(), k);
    std::vector<bool> combinations(total_combinations);

    size_t count = 0;
    for (auto const & str : combs)
    {
        if (str.size() != k)
        {
            // You can either ignore those mismatches or break
            continue;
        }
        size_t pos = index_of(str, base);
        if (pos == std::string::npos)
        {   
            // This string doesn't belong to the possible combinations. It's
            // unclear if OP want to ignore this case or consider it a mismatch
            continue;
        }
        if ( combinations[pos] )
        {
            // This is a duplicate. Again, it can be ignored or not.
            continue;
        }
        combinations[pos] = true;
        ++count;
    }

    return count == total_combinations;    
}

// Evaluate the index as a number in base n (number of elements in the base string)
size_t index_of(std::string const &candidate, std::string const &source)
{
    size_t result = 0, base = 1;
    for (auto c = candidate.crbegin(); c != candidate.crend(); ++c)
    {
        size_t pos = source.find(*c);
        if (pos == std::string::npos)
            return std::string::npos;
        result += pos * base;
        base *= source.size();
    }
    return result;
}
```